# How to display youtube video in background with full screen

Tags: html, css

I added youtube video in **background** but still it's not in full screen.

In left side and right side I'm still getting black background.

Here is my code:

```
<section class="banner-video">
    <div class="banner-video-inner">
       <iframe height="100%" width="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php the_field('banner_video_link');?>?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</section>


.banner-video{position: relative; z-index: 0; width:100%; height:650px;}
.banner-video-inner{ position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0;width: 100%;height: 100%;pointer-events: none; z-index: 2;}
```

I used the_field using advance custom field plugin.

so can anyone tell me how to show video in full screen and remove that left and right side black background ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.banner-video{position: relative; z-index: 0; width:100%; height:759px;}

@media only screen and (min-width:1400px){
.banner-video{height:843px;}
}

@media only screen and (min-width:1520px){
.banner-video{height:948px;}
}

@media only screen and (max-width:1199px){
.banner-video {height:576px;}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 992px){
.banner-video {height:432px;}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 640px){
.banner-video {height:318px;}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 400px){
.banner-video {height: 180px;}
}

Finally This Works for me. Got the video in full screen.
```

Answer (score 1):

Apply video to `video` tag and add CSS from below code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #000;
}
video {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  z-index: -100;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<video poster="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/polina.jpg" id="bgvid" playsinline autoplay muted loop>
  <source src="http://thenewcode.com/assets/videos/polina.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="http://thenewcode.com/assets/videos/polina.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: What about my code ?? Can you please give answer related to my code. Thanks